# Styling over string interpolation in HTML - Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

Let's say template receives string from component in one way binding, interpolation:

```
<span>{{list.members}}</span>
```

And it renders like

> 5 members

How can I edit string on HTML without changing anything on component so I can get bold number 5 and "members" left untouched:

> **5** members

Comment: You'd have to create a custom pipe and use like {{list.members | strongifyNumber}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a pipe solution:

strong-number.pipe.ts:

```
@Pipe({name: 'strongifyNumber'})

export class StrongifyNumber implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    let values: string[] = value.split(' ')
    if(values.length == 2){
        return ' <b>'+values[0]+'</b> ' + values[1];
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { StrongifyNumber } from './strong-number.pipe';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, StrongifyNumber
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [StrongifyNumber],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

template:

```
<span [innerHTML]="list.members | strongifyNumber"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have based on the answer of Visionstar credits to him

> The problem is, that the :first-letter doesn't work on
>   inline-element(such as span e.g), but on block/inline-block elements
>   (e.g. p, table caption, table cell, etc).
>   [Bold on span first letter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661751/bold-on-span-first-letter-not-working)

```css
span:first-of-type:first-letter 
{ font-weight: bold; }
p:first-of-type:first-letter 
{ font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<span style="display: block;">5 members</span>
<p>   5 members</p>
```

thanks to the comment of [aragorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1205647/aragorn)
for complete the answer in the case where you have a number greater than a digit I think you could use a js function to get the content of the span and edit it, as I saw other posts there are people who are waiting for CSS4, or a word selector for css that does not exist yet

```js
var text=$('#myspan').text()
first = text.slice(0, text.indexOf(" "));
other=text.slice(text.indexOf(" "), text.lenght);
var newdata="<span class='number'>"+first+"</span> "+other;
$('#myspan').html(newdata);
```

```css
span:first-of-type:first-letter 
{ font-weight: bold; 
  }
p:first-of-type:first-letter 
{ font-weight: bold; }

.number
{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="display: block;">5 members</span>
<p>   5 members</p>

<span  id="myspan" style="display: block;">100 members members</span>
```

Comment: if you're right I just tried with 2-digit numbers and boy to find a way to do it treating it as if it were a word, I think it would be better to have the data of the members separately or grouped in another label in this way would only be style to the label; or with Jquery access the content of the label and replace it

Comment: There is no :firstWord in css unfortunately

Comment: yes I know, CSS4 selector maybe ? in a distant future

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the value in the component.ts file and keep in separate variables the "members" word and the "number".

```
const value = "5 members".split(" ");
const membersLabel = value[1];
const membersValue = value[0];
```

Having them separate, you can style it as you like

```
<strong>membersValue</strong> <span>{{membersLabel}}</span>
```

It's not that bullet proof though. You should write it in a way to prevent the cases in which you won't have the pattern "# members";